# Batch script with powershell command (run from task scheduler)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I am using a batch script with a powershell command.
cutout:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%v IN (`powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass "& { (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).DayOfYear }"`) DO set "DayOfYear=00%%v"
set DayOfYear=%DayOfYear:~-3%

set rinex_dest=E:\02_RINEX\%GNSSWEEK%\%DayOfYear%\
set rinex_dest_extern=E:\02_RINEX\%GNSSWEEK%\%DayOfYear%\extern\
IF NOT EXIST (mkdir %rinex_dest%)
IF NOT EXIST (mkdir %rinex_dest_extern%)
CD %rinex_dest%

set temp_unzip=%rinex_dest%temp_unzip\
set temp_nw=%rinex_dest%temp_nw\
set temp_extern=%rinex_dest%temp_extern\
mkdir %temp_unzip%
mkdir %temp_nw%
mkdir %temp_extern%

7z.exe e Y:\data\%Year%\%Month%\%Day%\*.zip -o%temp_unzip% *_MO.rnx -r

FOR %%i IN (%NWStationen%) DO MOVE %temp_unzip%%%i00DEU_S_%Year%%DayOfYear%*_MO.rnx %temp_nw%
FOR %%h IN (%externeStationen%) DO MOVE %temp_unzip%%%h_S_%Year%%DayOfYear%*_MO.rnx %temp_extern%
rmdir /Q /S %temp_unzip%
```

This works fine for me, if i run the the batchfile.
But now i try to implement the batchfile in the task scheduler (on Win Server 2019).
The batchfile runs, but the powershell command doesn`t work.

The Action in task scheduler is:

```
"Start program" C:\Windows\System32\CMD.exe /c"PatchtoScript\Script.bat"
```

Any suggestions to solve the problem?
Thank You!

Comment: Maybe it's expecting a powershell variable? Is the batch file long? You should be able to just run the ps1 by itself

Comment: it does not work when scheduled.. well, what is the rest of the code doing? How did you determine the variable was not set, because that is all you are showing right now.

Comment: It`s round about 200 lines long.

Comment: sure, but you must be using that variable somewhere, that is how you know if is not working. So please clarify. are you writing to an output file?

Comment: @Gerhard it uses the DayOfYear to copy some files and work with them.
I used the same script (without the ps code over months without any probelms)
Before the ps code i entered the DayOfYear manually.

Comment: ok, so show me, by editing your question and posting how you are performing that functions.

Comment: When i run the batchscript dy doubleclick it works fine. That`s why i think tne task scheduler must be the problem

Comment: I am asking one more time to show me in the question, the code you have written to perform that function. There is a HUGE difference between double click and scheduled tasks.

Comment: Thanks. One more question, show me how you've set variables `%temp_unzip%`, `%temp_mw%` and `%temp_extern%`

Comment: Y: is a network drive! Could this be the problem?

Comment: @ambiguityfix please take the [tour] and read [ask] a good question. You must always provide a [mcve] of your code so that anyone here helping can copying and paste the code themselves so they can attempt to replicate your problem. As it stand right now your code is not complete which makes it unverifiable.

Comment: If the task is configured to run regardless of a user that is logged in then YES, the problem is the mapped Y: drive.  Task scheduler is not running within your user context and it doesn't map drives before the task runs.  You need to use UNC paths.

Comment: is your batch file also on ``E:\``? and are these drives local or network drives?

Comment: @Gerhard Yes, it is alos on E:\. And this is a local drive.

Comment: so Y is a network drive, then exactly as @Squashman posted a comment before mine. The scheduled task is not aware of the mapped drive.

Comment: I would do the whole thing in powershell and it's probably easier.

Comment: BTW, I'm a little suprised at this stage that nobody has mentioned, especially as you've stated that your script works for you, that `IF NOT EXIST (mkdir %rinex_dest%)` and `IF NOT EXIST (mkdir %rinex_dest_extern%)` are completely invalid commands, I'd wager that they should read `If Not Exist "%rinex_dest%" MD "%rinex_dest%"` and `If Not Exist "%rinex_dest_extern%" MD "%rinex_dest_extern%"`. And in this case, possibly both replaced by `MD "%rinex_dest_extern%" 2>NUL`.

Comment: In addition, you do not need `UseBackQ`, or `Delims=` or `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` or in fact adding leading `0`'s and then trimming later to the last three characters. Example: `For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).DayOfYear.ToString('000')" 2^>NUL') Do Set "DayOfYear=%%G"`.

Comment: I'd also be interested in how your created your variables `%Year%` `%Month%` and `%Day%`, earlier in your code, because it seems to me as if those should probably have been assigned using `Get-Date` in `powershell.exe` too. I'd then advise that it would probably have been more efficient to have defined all of those in one `For /F` loop earlier in the code.  Because one call to the powershell executable is going to be quicker than two, more especially if you're using exactly the same cmdlet.

Comment: @Compo, noticed all of that including quite a few other issues, but did not bother mentioning simply because OP states that script works on double click, so who am I to argue with that logic...

Comment: @js2010 Sure that would be ideal, but OP stated in a comment that it is a 200 line script (though some lines do absolutely nothing)

Comment: I'd wager @Gerhard, looking at what they've posted, that I could, if so inclined, reduce their 200 lines down to double figures! _Although once I add the multitude of missing best practice doublequotes, even with all of the unnecessary trailing backward slashes removed, their script byte size probably wouldn't reduce by half!_

Comment: Indeed, that is true @Compo